# Child to trigger parent function with parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child

I'm using React hook and trying to pass some parameters from child to parent function when the event `onChange` takes place but it shows error `answerHandler not a function`.

**Parent View :**

```
export default function Setting() {
    ...

    const answerHandler = (questionId, answerId) => {
        // some codes here
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Question answerHandler={answerHandler} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Child View :**

```
export default function Question({ answerHandler }) {
    ...

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="answer"
                onChange={answerHandler(1, 2)}
                value="1"
            /> &nbsp; Answer 1
        </div>
    );
}
```

**EDIT:**

The main error shows only `TypeError: answerHandler is not a function` which is showing the file path something like `path-url-here/Question.js:68` and pointing to the error line on `onChange={answerHandler(1, 2)}`

And also, it is working if there is no parameters to pass.

Comment: can you please show the full error log ?

Answer (score 0):

you should not write your answerHandler function in child like that when you have parameters. because it is called on render and may cause error or infinite loop on each render.try that like this :

**Child view:**

```js
export default function Question({ answerHandler }) {
    ...

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="answer"
                onChange={()=>answerHandler(1, 2)}
                value="1"
            /> &nbsp; Answer 1
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I did try this method but still the same error.

Comment: have you tried to define your parent and child components in arrow function mode? maybe it helps

Comment: I tried that too but not working at all. I wonder why is it not working when there is parameters need to be passed.